# How can i configure a SOAP over HTTP listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I have been looking at several resources online for a concrete example of the above issue. I want to develop an endpoint that accepts messages coming in from a SOAP Server and in turn send appropriate responses.So far the only useful  guides i have seen are in the alternative SOAP over JMS spec. Is there anywhere i can find useful information/articles on how to achieve this in Spring Boot ?

Or alternatively can i be able to configure a listener endpoint (using SOAP over JMS) against a  server (using SOAP over HTTP)

Comment: Hello. Did you read this : [Producing a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) ?

Comment: Yes i already have a Spring SOAP service running (the mock server sending the requests). Ideally i want now to configure an endpoint/destination where i should be able to log messages (in console ) as they are delivered . I have seen this in quite a few examples but only that its SOAP over JMS

Comment: Do you have a JMS broker yet ?

Comment: i have ActiveMQ configured

Comment: Do you have JMS producer and consumer yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do .. But...

Just create a soap webservice?

http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-web-services-starter

Or do you want to create a sniffer? Catch the soap envelope and pass it on?

Comment: yes i want to create a sniffer. I want to pass on the message to some other endpoint